# How to save the interleaved values of an array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I don't know how to put it in words, but I can with an example. I have the following variable

```
anglesp = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi,50)
```

but I want to extract to a new variable the values at the position 0,2,4,...,50 and so on. Something like this:

```
angles = anglesp[0,2,4,6...]
```

Comment: `anglesp[::2]`  would do what you want ... but so would `np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi,25)`

Comment: Try ```anglesp[0:51:2]```

Comment: @JoranBeasley, `np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 25)` doesn't give the same points as `np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)[::2]`--there is an off-by-oneish problem with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numpy arrays can take an iterable (of integers) as an index instead of a single position index. In this case, the `[]` operation will return a new array containing the items at the specified positions within the iterable.

As an example:

```py
>>> A = np.array([0,10,20,30,40])
>>> idx = [0, 2, 4]
>>> A[idx]
np.array([0, 20, 40])
```

So, in your case, you simply need:

```py
angles = anglesp[range(0,50+1,2)]
```

Comment: It works, but it is more complicated than necessary.  NumPy arrays can be indexed with slices, so you can write `anglesp[::2]` to extract every other element.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Very true. Slicing is quicker, but it only works with equally spaced elements. Creating an index variable separately allows you to select any arbitrary subset of the array. So it's more general

Comment: (I am sure you knew what I commented. I posted it the counter argument for tutorial purposes)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.take()` which is faster than “fancy” indexing (indexing arrays using arrays);

```
import  as np
a = [10, 30, 8, 5, 1, 2]
indices = [0, 1, 4] #make this range(0,51,2) for your example
np.take(a, indices)
```

it can be easier to use if you need elements along a given axis for a multiple dimension array. A call such as `np.take(arr, indices, axis=3)` is equivalent to `arr[:,:,:,indices,...]`
ref:https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html

> Example

```
    import numpy as np
    a=np.array([[ 3290  5847]
 [ 7682  6957]
 [22660  5482]
 [22661 10965]
 [    7  1477]
 [ 7681     3]
 [17541 15717]
 [ 9139  1475]
 [14251  4400]
 [ 7680  9140]
 [ 4758 22289]
 [ 7679  8407]
 [20101 15718]
 [15716  8405]
 [15710 20829]
 [22662    19]])
 print("-------")
 print(np.take(a,(2,4),axis=0))
```

Output:

```
[[22660  5482]
 [    7  1477]]
```

Comment: wow, thanks for pointing out that this function exists. You are right, it's way more convenient for multi-dimensional arrays